# How to deal with unresolved inclusion in eclipse in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, include

I import two self-defined project: projectA and projectB 
the classes in projectA include headers in project B
but eclipse always show some yellow and red lines to say that unresolved inclusion.
(I am sure that all the syntax and setting about include are correct, since they are projects has been developed and used for a long time)
How to deal with that?

do I need to right click project and do index->rebuild or something else?

Comment: I don't code  C++ in Eclipse, but with Java and ActionScript in Eclipse - one has to make a project dependent on another in Eclipse and include it in (include/library) path etc. Did you do that?

Comment: yes, I think all the settings and syntax are correct

Answer (score 1):

You can set path to the header files of projectB in projectA under:

> Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Compiler ->
>   Includes

[image]

Comment: there is no complier under setttings

Comment: Compiler means that you have to select your current compiler, IE GCC Compiler. I will update my answer with a picture.

Comment: It seems that we use different version of eclipse, I do not have Tool Setting

Comment: and the configuration is Build, not Debug, and it can not be changed(in grey)

Comment: under c/c++ Build->discovery Options, it says "this project is not a CDT project"

Comment: is that a problem??? What I did to import the projects is that import->General->existing projects into workspace

Comment: Which verison of eclipse are you using? I have Juno, you can find the last Eclipse CDT here http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/. If it says that "this project is not a CDT project" maybe the .cproject file is missing. In that case the .project file still marks the project to be C/C++ but the actual C settings can't be loaded.